# Calendar icon on datetime bootstrap picker notshowing

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datetimepicker

I have this datetime picker but only calendar icon wont show, other icons are showing correctly.

```
<link href='https://apollo.telekomcg.com/fonts/fonts.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-combobox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-filestyle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-dialog.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/EArchiveNew.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/colResizable-1.5.min.js"></script>
<%--<link href="Css/VarPL.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />--%>
<link href="Css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Css/bootstrap-switch.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Css/bootstrap-combobox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Css/bootstrap-datepicker3.standalone.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Css/bootstrap-datepicker3.standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Css/bootstrap-dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Here are my scripts. I am using asp.net web forms.

This is my calendar

```
<div class='input-group date' style="width: 250px !important" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD">
                        <input type='text' id='untilDate' class="form-control" runat="server" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

It wont show and i cant figure out why.

Comment: The amount of external scripts and CSS you are loading is horrible. - **1)** DO NOT load script or CSS and its minified version. -- Just that should help. **2)** Edit your question with the cleaned code. Make it a runnable snippet.

Comment: What is version of the Bootstrap you are using there?

Comment: Make sure Glyphicons are included to your stylesheet.

Comment: All other glyphicons are loading fine, only this one wont.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need that many imports, here is an example using your HTML an the essentials of bootstrap 5

EDIT:

your HTMl was just missing the part that displays the icon:

```
<span class="input-group-text bg-light d-block">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </span>
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('#datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="input-group date" id="datepicker" style="width: 250px !important" data-date-format="yyyy-MM-DD">
  <input type='text' id='untilDate' class="form-control" runat="server" />
  <span class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text bg-light d-block">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </span>
  </span>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: You post helps to provide minimal and reproducible example, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: firstly shouldn't they be the judge of that , without a minimal and reproducible example it at least gives them a point of reference to work from to see what they missed, not sure it qualify s a down vote

Comment: The snippet has the same problem as described in the question. So, it's not helpful.

Comment: ah fair point i can admit I id miss that, my sincere apologies, have amended the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 3 your code should work as expected:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#untilDate').datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
  <input id="untilDate" type="text" class="form-control">
  <div class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Therefore I guess you are using Bootstrap 4 or later. If yes, please note the [following changes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#components):

> Dropped the Glyphicons icon font. If you need icons, some options are:
>
> - the upstream version of Glyphicons
> - Octicons
> - Font Awesome
> - See the Extend page for a list of alternatives. Have additional suggestions? Please open an issue or PR.

So, in this case you need to clearly use Font Awesome or another icon set as suggested by @PatricHume:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#untilDate').datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
  <input id="untilDate" type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text d-block">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I just wanted to say that I managed to fix this. The fix that I have done is probably stupid and I don't know why this works. In bootsrap.css and bootstrap.min.js I commented glyphicon-calendar:before{} and it showed on my calendar. If someone can explain it would be good.

Comment: ideally you shouldn't need to change the bootsrap.css and bootstrap.min.js, I hope the answer i gave above gives you better way to fix the issue